# using the github API, Create git pull request without checking out the code

Tags: git, github, github-api

How can I create a github pull request for a project that I haven't checked out using the github api. I want to automate simple changes to repositories, that I need not check out first. I simply want to pull a file from raw.githubusercontent.com modify it and create said pull request.

**EDIT** The github web user interface allows to edit foreign files by cloning and creating a pull request in the back ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The api supports cloning remotly

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork

Answer (score 10):

2015:

> I haven't checked out using the github api.

You should at least have forked the repo first (see [GitHub API create a fork](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork))

Then "[Create a Pull Request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request)" supposes you have pushed a commit to a dedicated branch (API "[Create a commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#create-a-commit)" first, which supposes to [create a tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#create-a-tree) first, based on [creating a blob](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#create-a-blob)).

For all those operations, I would suggest using a wrapper to the GitHub API like **[`go-github`](https://github.com/google/go-github)**, which might make the all series of operation easier to chain.

---

2023:

The [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli) allows for:

- [`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) to create a fork of a repository (without cloning it locally).
- [`gh pr create --web`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create) to create a pull request on GitHub, from the web interface (so no local checkout required, assuming you have a branch ready to be merged).

Comment: I need to do the same thing as OP: checkout a single file from a repo, make changes to it, commit them to a new branch, and open a PR from it. Haven't tested it yet, but maybe the ["contents" add/update file](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28) endpoints could help with this. Looks like you can specify a `path` of exactly what to change. It also looks like you could check out a specific `path`, presumably meaning you wouldn't have to clone the whole repo just to get one file.

Comment: @V.Rubinetti Why not just edit the file directly on github.com? As illustrated in [this article](https://dev.to/flaviocopes/how-to-make-your-first-pull-request-on-github-1m8g): "You’re editing a file in a project you don’t have write access to. Submitting a change to this file will write it to a new branch in your fork flaviocopes/web.dev, so you can send a pull request."

Answer (score 2):

You had to have checked it out, but you can use scripted command line to do it.

A pull request asks that a particular git commit be merged into the main repository, not that a set of edits be made to files.  You can only merge in commits if you have a writable copy of the github repo, which you can only get by cloning or forking the project.